# Regex not working for multiple characters

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I want to search and replace special characters of markdown (viz `` \`*_{}[]()#+.!|- ``) from the given string.

I am able to make it work in C# easily since there is verbatim @ but Javascript not getting what's the issue. It seems something to do with `/g` , I read in another post which asked to use `replaceAll` but I could not find that method for `string`

#### C# version

```cs
string test = @"B 
*H*
C
**AB**";
Console.WriteLine ("Input    " + test);

var pattern = @"[\\`*_{}\[\]()#+-.!]";
var _1 = Regex.Replace (test, "\r?\n", "<br/>");
var out_ = Regex.Replace (_1, pattern, m => @"\" + m.Value);
Console.WriteLine ("Output   " + out_);
```

#### Typescript Version

```js
const regexM = new RegExp(/[\\\`\*\_\{\}\[\]\(\)#\+-\.!\|]/g, 'm');

var input = `B 
*H*
C
**AB**`;

var inputString = input.replace(regexM, function (y: any) { return "\\" + y; });

if (/\r|\n/.exec(inputString))
{
    inputString = inputString .replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br/>");
}

inputString = inputString.replace(regexM, function (x: any)
{
    return "\\" + x;
});
```

Expected: `B <br/>\*H\*<br/>C<br/>\*\*AB\*\*`

I am getting  `B <br/>\*H*<br/>C<br/>**AB**`

Comment: Are you sure there is `inputString = valueString.replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br/>")`? What is `valueString`?

Comment: sorry, its `inputString` forgot to change it while making a MVCE here. Updated the question.

Comment: Just note there is  a bug in C# code (the pattern containing `-`). And instead of lambda expressions, you may use `$&` in the string replacement pattern, same way as in JS. Do you want me  to add a fixed C# code snippet?

Comment: Thats ok. I mostly work on C# , so I was trying this conversion in it first since its faster for me to understand and implement in JS. As you mentioned escaping `-` should work

Comment: At any rate, here is a C# tweak: ``var pattern = @"[][\\`*_{}()#+.!-]";`` and `var out_ = Regex.Replace (_1, pattern, @"\$&");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```js
const regexM = /[\\`*_{}[\]()#+.!|-]/g;

var input = `B 
*H*
C
**AB**`;

var inputString = input.replace(regexM, "\\$&");
inputString = inputString.replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br/>");
console.log(inputString);
// => B <br/>\*H\*<br/>C<br/>\*\*AB\*\*
```

NOTE:

- The `-` in the `regexM` regex forms a range, you need to either escape it or - as in the code above - put it at the end of the character class
- Rather than using callback methods, in order to reference the whole match, you may use the `$&` placeholder in a string replacement pattern
- When you define the regex using a regex literal, there is only one backslash needed to form a regex escape, so `` const regexM = /[\\`*_{}[\]()#+.!|-]/g `` is equal to `` const regexM = new RegExp("[\\\\`*_{}[\\]()#+.!|-]", "g") ``
- There is no need to check if there is a line break char or not with `if (/\r|\n/.exec(inputString))`, just run `.replace`.